# I need a support for sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns lower range,upper range,  discount amount
I am passing a number and finding in which range it belongs to and retrieving its discount amount
But i am passing a number that not in this table in this case i need the last range discount amount from table 
I need a sql query for the same

```
 0-10 100 
11-20 200 
21-30 300
```

- if i am passing 5 need to get 100
- if i am passing 15 200 as result
- but if i am passing 50 i need to get 300 as result

Ie.  If the value that is passing not in the range need to get the highest ranges discount amount.

Plzz help. Mee

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  What if there are gaps in the table?

Comment: 0-10 100 , 11-20 200 , 21-30 300 if i am passing 5 need to get 100 , if i am passing 15 200 as result, but if i am passing 50 i need to get 300

Comment: Edit the question with that info. To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: Post your script so far you written. This will help as you are already getting correct output for initial two range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can directly pass/use @value in the script as well.

```
DECLARE @Value INT 
SET @Value = 35

SELECT SUM(DISCOUNT) Discount 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN upper_range = (SELECT MAX(upper_range) FROM your_table) AND @Value > upper_range THEN DISCOUNT 
        WHEN @Value BETWEEN  lower_range AND upper_range THEN DISCOUNT 
        ELSE 0 
    END
    DISCOUNT 
    FROM your_table
) A
```

Output for value 35 is-

```
300
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ALL:

```
select discount
from tablename
where x between lowerrange and upperrange
union all
select max(discount) from tablename
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where x between lowerrange and upperrange
)
```

If the 1st query does not return a result, then the value will be fetched by the 2nd query.
If the 1st query returns a result, then the 2nd will not return anything. 
Applies to any major rdbms.

Comment: If there is no range for given number then it will give highest range discount amount?

Comment: It will give the highest discount amount (based on your sample data).

Comment: select max(discount) from tablename
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where x between lowerrange and upperrange
) Can you explain this code Select 1 means

Comment: Select 1 means that there exists a row with that condition.

Comment: So not exits.. means that there is not a row with that condition and in this case fetch the maximum discount

Comment: If this resolve your problem remember mark it as the correct answer using the green tick.